# How do I set the selected column sort in datatables?

Tags: datatables

Basically, you can do `.order(2)` on your datatable for example to order by that column.

This works great, however it clears the sort header icons (the two arrows up and down) so you can't see which column is being sorted.

I want to make it sort exactly as if you'd clicked the column header.

[image]

The above image is the column header zoomed in with the first row. You can see it's sorting by date as the first arrow is black.

When I call `.order()` it orders the table by date, but it clears the arrows, like in the bottom one. This is what I'm trying to fix.

Edit - Code:

```
var addedRow = dataTable.row.add([a, b, moment(someDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"), d]);

dataTable.order(2);

dataTable.draw();
```

Comment: Can you show how you call Datatables API order()? Which version you use?

Comment: I've added my code, it just adds a row and then calls order to order it on column 2 (the date column). The table then orders but the header doesn't show it's ordered by date. DataTables version is 1.10.18

Comment: dataTable.order(2); is wrong you should use dataTable.order([2,'asc']).draw(); Refer https://datatables.net/reference/api/order(). Use an array of column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables [Order()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) api is used to get/set ordering applied to the table.

An example code to use Datatables **order()** :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var order = table.order([1,'ASC']);
```

You can refer the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) for more function types and example.